# SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', 'Pappu Akondo', 'Java')' at line 238.

This message is shown when I submit the form. Here `Pappu Akondo` is author field value and `java` is Tags field value.

My HTML code

```
 <div class="block">               
        <form action="addpost.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table class="form">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Title</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Post Title..." class="medium" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Category</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="select" name="cat">
                            <option>Select category</option>
                            <?php
                            $query = "select * from tbl_category";
                            $result = $db->select($query);
                            if ($result) {
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Upload Image</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="image"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 9px;">
                        <label>Content</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="body" class="tinymce"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Author</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter Author name..." class="medium" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Tags</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Enter tags here..." class="medium" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Save" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['title']);
    $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['cat']);
    $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['body']);
    $author = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['author']);
    $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['tags']);

    $permited = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $div = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_image = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_ext;
    $uploaded_image = "upload/" . $unique_image;
    if ($title == "" || $cat == "" || $body == "" || $file_name == "" || $author == "" || $tags == "") {
        echo "<span class='error'>Field must not be empty !!</span>";
    } elseif ($file_size > 1048567) {
        echo "<span class='error'>Image Size should be less then 1MB! </span>";
    } elseif (in_array($file_ext, $permited) === false) {
        echo "<span class='error'>You can upload only:-"
            . implode(', ', $permited) . "</span>";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_post`(cat, title, body, image, author, tags) 
        VALUES('$cat', '$title', '$body', $uploaded_image', '$author', '$tags')";
        $inserted_rows = $db->insert($query);
        if ($inserted_rows) {
            echo "<span class='success'>Data Inserted Successfully.</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span class='error'>Data Not Inserted !</span>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing quote before `$uploaded_image`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_post`(cat, title, body, image, author, tags) 
    VALUES('$cat', '$title', '$body', '$uploaded_image', '$author', '$tags')";
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)